# Reformulating the AMPL car example

Tags: pyomo

I am trying migrating the ampl car problem that comes in the Ipopt source code tarball as example. I am having got problems with the end condition (reach a place with zero speed at final iteration) and with the cost function (minimize final time).

Can someone help me revise the following model?

```
# min tf
# dx/dt = 0
# dv/dt = a - R*v^2
# x(0) = 0; x(tf) = 100
# v(0) = 0; v(tf) = 0
# -3 <= a <= 1 (a is the control variable)

#!Python3.5
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.dae import *

N = 20;
T = 10;
L = 100;

m = ConcreteModel()

# Parameters
m.R = Param(initialize=0.001)

# Variables
def x_init(m, i):
    return i*L/N

m.t = ContinuousSet(bounds=(0,1000))
m.x = Var(m.t, bounds=(0,None), initialize=x_init)
m.v = Var(m.t, bounds=(0,None), initialize=L/T)
m.a = Var(m.t, bounds=(-3.0,1.0), initialize=0)

# Derivatives
m.dxdt = DerivativeVar(m.x, wrt=m.t)
m.dvdt = DerivativeVar(m.v, wrt=m.t)

# Objetives
m.obj = Objective(expr=m.t[N])

# DAE
def _ode1(m, i):
    if i==0:
        return Constraint.Skip
    return m.dxdt[i] == m.v[i]
m.ode1 = Constraint(m.t, rule=_ode1)

def _ode2(m, i):
    if i==0:
        return Constraint.Skip
    return m.dvdt[i] == m.a[i] - m.R*m.v[i]**2
m.ode2 = Constraint(m.t, rule=_ode2)

# Constraints
def _init(m):
    yield m.x[0] == 0
    yield m.v[0] == 0
    yield ConstraintList.End
m.init = ConstraintList(rule=_init)

'''
def _end(m, i):
    if i==N:
        return m.x[i] == L amd m.v[i] == 0
    return Constraint.Skip
m.end = ConstraintList(rule=_end)
'''

# Discretize
discretizer = TransformationFactory('dae.finite_difference')
discretizer.apply_to(m, nfe=N, wrt=m.t, scheme='BACKWARD')

# Solve
solver = SolverFactory('ipopt', executable='C:\\EXTERNOS\\COIN-OR\\win32-msvc12\\bin\\ipopt')
results = solver.solve(m, tee=True)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, a ContinuousSet in Pyomo has to be bounded. This means that in order to solve a minimum time optimal control problem using this tool, the problem must be reformulated to remove the time scaling from the ContinuousSet. In addition, you have to introduce an extra variable to represent the final time. I've added an example to the [Pyomo github repository](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/master/examples/dae/car_example.py) showing how this can be done for your problem.

Comment: Awesome!!! It's the same way as ampl did, using an independent variable for time. Same concept, but really different syntax, Thanks a lot!